# how do I change a UITabBarItem action?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbar

The main window of my iOS application contains a UITabBarController. There're 3 UITabBarItem and they show a different view each.

I think the tab bar was directly created with the xcode tab bar application template. Now I created another view and I want to replace the existing one with the new one but I don't see any code that assign a view to the UITabBarItem button. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to perform this action in code then look at this UITabBarController method

[setViewControllers:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITabBarController/setViewControllers%3aanimated%3a)

Sample code

```
NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: controller1, controller2, controller3, nil];
[tabBar setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:YES];
```

If you using IB, then assign required UIViewController to your tab.

Comment: And how are the controllers set by now? I don't see this anywhere in the code or in the xib parameters...

Comment: I guess you use IB. See this image - http://img440.imageshack.us/img440/5532/screenshot20120131at155.png

Comment: Indeed I use IB. Thanks for opening my eyes :)

Answer (score 0):

You could place your custom tabs over the view of your UITabBarController at the right position, but them you need to handle all the Tab switching by yourself, which is not too hard.